# Digital Archeology: "Integer.h" and "Rational.h"

Tags: math, g++

I am trying to get the "Real/Expr" library to build on modern systems: https://cs.nyu.edu/exact/realexpr/exact.html

It depends on a "Integer.h" and "Rational.h" header, supposedly implementing "big integer" and rational math, and supposedly part of the GNU project. So far I was unable to locate the original headers, and as the library was originally published around 1997 a lot of information has been lost. I implemented those classes "blindly" on top of GMP, though it is hard to see if my implementation matches the expected behaviour. Unfortunately I don't have contact details for the original author.

Yes, I googled the headers, and "Integer.h" is not a rare filename.

So, my question is, has anyone used this library in the past, and may have still its dependencies? Does anyone remember "well known" Integer.h or Rational.h, maybe from a predecessor of the GMP library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by a user on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/:

> These headers are from libg++, the version from 1997 was "2.7.2". You find it on one of the old GCC mirror sites (see gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html), which points, for example, to ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/gcc/old-releases/libg++

I didn't have any good hits on Google for this, so hopefully this helps others.